# Secure way to save access and refresh token in web application client

Tags: web-applications, access-token, smartgwt

I'm creating web application with Spring as server and SmartGWT as client. For authentication there is token mechanism (using JWT but it's irrelevant).

When SmartGWT application starts it's there's login modal - user enter login and password and login request is send to server. In response client gets access token and refresh token.

Right now I save both tokens in singleton class and they are used for further requests to server and refreshing access token.

Problem is that after refreshing website SmartGWT application starts again and data in singleton class is lost so user have to login again.

Expectations are that if access token is valid user won't have to sign in again.

Is there any way to do it SECURELY? I could save tokens in cookies but it's not very save.